# Fetch data for a date range in dynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

I am using Serverless and DynamoDB and am relatively new to it. My app has a table called Trips. The parameters of the tables are {id, route, cost, selling, type, date, LR, asset } and a bunch of other irrelevant document numbers, where id is generated by uuid.

According to this guide for ordering data in a date range (see 5th row in the table at the end) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-modeling-nosql-B.html I have added a parameter called `createdAt` which is a random integer from 1 to 20 sent by frontend and made a `GSI` with `HASH key` as createdAT and `SORT key` as `date`.

I ran 20 promises concurrently for keeping createdAt from 1 to 20.  I am simply combining all the results in one object like this.

```
await Promise.all(promises).then(function (values) {
      console.log(values);
      values.map((value) => {
        value.map((v) => {
          tripdata.push(v);
        });
      });
    });
```

Here is the response

```
 [
 [
{
  Cost: 12128,
  date: '2020-04-01',
  RouteShortCode: 'Hazira-Manjusar-Sudeep',
  Selling: 11000,
  Type: 'Export'
},
{
  Cost: 12581,
  date: '2020-04-24',
  RouteShortCode: 'Hazira-Nandesari-Kevin',
  Selling: 10000,
  Type: 'Export'
}
],
[
{
  Cost: 12691,
  date: '2020-04-09',
  RouteShortCode: 'Hazira-Nandesari-Kevin',
  Selling: 10000,
  Type: 'Export'
}
],
[
{
  Cost: 11536,
  date: '2020-04-09',
  RouteShortCode: 'Hazira-Nandesari-Omega',
  Selling: 29000,
  Type: 'Import'
},
{
  Cost: 8973.5,
  date: '2020-04-18',
  RouteShortCode: 'Hazira-Manjusar-Sudeep',
  Selling: 11000,
  Type: 'Export'
}
],
[
{
  Cost: 11665,
  date: '2020-04-20',
  RouteShortCode: 'Hazira-Nandesari-Kevin',
  Selling: 10000,
  Type: 'Export'
}
],
]
```

Serverless.yml for tripsTable

```
tripTable:
  Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
  Properties:
    AttributeDefinitions:
      [
        { "AttributeName": "id", "AttributeType": "S" },
        { "AttributeName": "date", "AttributeType": "S" },
        { "AttributeName": "createdAt", "AttributeType": "N" },
        { "AttributeName": "Asset", "AttributeType": "S" },
      ]
    # { "AttributeName": "Route", "AttributeType": "S" },
    KeySchema:
      [
        { "AttributeName": "date", "KeyType": "HASH" },
        { "AttributeName": "id", "KeyType": "RANGE" },
      ]
    ProvisionedThroughput:
      ReadCapacityUnits: 5
      WriteCapacityUnits: 5
    StreamSpecification:
      StreamViewType: "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"
    TableName: ${self:provider.environment.TRIPS}
    GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
      - IndexName: DateVSTrips
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: createdAt
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: date
            KeyType: RANGE
        Projection:

          ProjectionType: "ALL"
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: "5"
          WriteCapacityUnits: "5"

    LocalSecondaryIndexes:
      - IndexName: TripsVSRoutes
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: date
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: Asset
            KeyType: RANGE
        Projection:
          ProjectionType: ALL
```

But the issue is the entry on 2020/04/01 and 2020/04/24 have the same createdAt parameter, hence after combining all array results the final result is not ordered by date.

Do I need to sort this list again or am i missing something here? If I need to sort it again won't it become much more inefficient?

Comment: Does it work,or you have problems?

Comment: @RichardRublev No the final result is not sorted by date, which creates a problem since I need that data for graph. I've added the response, please check

Comment: Show us your serverelss.yml.

Comment: @RichardRublev added

Comment: Do you want to sort the result by `date`? Or by `createdAt`? And please show us the `query` or `scan`.

Answer (score 0):

DDB will not be able to return the data to you in a sorted list as you are doing 20 separate parallel queries.

You will need to sort the entire list yourself, once you have all 20 results.

That being said, do you really have the volume required for the structure you're using?

The page you linked to has the following

> For example, assume that you expect the following:
>
> Up to 2 million orders will be in the system, growing to 3 million in
>   5 years.
>
> Up to 20 percent of these orders will be in an OPEN state at any given
>   time.
>
> The average order record is around 100 bytes, with three OrderItem
>   records in the order partition that are around 50 bytes each, giving
>   you an average order entity size of 250 bytes.
>
> For that table, the N factor calculation would look like the
>   following.
>
> ItemsPerRCU = 4KB / 250B = 16
>
> PartitionMaxReadRate = 3K * 16 = 48K
>
> N = (0.2 * 3M) / 48K = 13

If you've run the calculations and rounded up to 20, then fine.

Comment: Sorry I did not make the calculations, I'll do it. What do you mean by having the volume required for this structure? I am also concerned about what would happen if the result of these 20 queries is in say thousands and all of that needs to be sorted. Would that be a performance issue?

Comment: By volume I mean how much read/write activity?  That basically the calculation being done.  Yes, if you're pulling back enough records you're going to see a performance issue trying to sort them at some point...

Comment: What would you recommed doing here then? How can I make a change to accomodate this feature?